# need to show then hide a link using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of text which says (show map steps) which when clicked slides down a a div with info on interacting with a map. I'd like to change the text to say "hide map steps" after the div slides down which when clicked will sldie everything back up.

It mostly works. I have "hide map steps" set to display: none but you can't use it as a link to slide everything back up.

Here's the code I am using:

```
$(".stepsLink").click(function () {
$(".stepsLink").hide();
$(".stepsUpLink").show();
if ($(".steps").is(":hidden")) {
  $(".steps").slideDown("fast", "linear");
} else {
  $(".steps").slideUp("fast", "linear");
}
});
```

The stepsUpLink shows itself but isn't clickable to slide the div back up.

Here's my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ltdesign/5b6XS/

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first line to this:
    `$(".stepsLink, .stepsUpLink").click(function () {`

Comment: I also added:   $(".stepsLink").show();
   $(".stepsUpLink").hide(); to get the show and hide to toggle back and forth. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stepsLink").click(function () {
        if ($(".steps").is(":hidden")) {   
            $(".steps").slideDown("fast", "linear", function(){
              $(".stepsLink").html('hide map steps <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>');
            });
        } else {
            $(".steps").slideUp("fast", "linear", function(){
                $(".stepsLink").html('show map steps <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>');
            });
        }                 
      });
});
```

## [**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/KTP9q/3/)

Comment: This is way to much code to accomplish what the poster is want to achieve. As a matter of practice, its always a wee bit better to remove/hide one control before showing another. The second block has the show first and you could get visual overlap.  My bad on the downvote.  Edit the answer and I will remove.

Comment: Just as a general rule, doubling code and adding unnecessary (from the posters question) libraries increase maintenance costs and decrease performance.  Cheers:)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love jQueryUI, but this looks like much a much cleaner approach.  There is a slight delay when the toggle occurs for the labels when i run on jsFiddle.  Moving the $.html() out of the function would correct and improve response.  Good move on the removal of the second link.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I've put the html() inside the function so if show/hide function doesn't work it will stay as it is

Comment: Wasn't worried at all.  Just noticed the response delay in the label switch.  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You only have the `click` event on the stepsLink span, not on the stepsUpLink one - it does not handle click.

Answer (score 0):

@jqueryrocks has a good approach, just needs one little tweak.  Move your show hide into the condition so that the labels will appear correctly once clicked.

```
$(".stepsLink, .stepsUpLink").click(function () {

    if ($(".steps").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".stepsLink").hide();
        $(".stepsUpLink").show();
        $(".steps").slideDown("fast", "linear");
    } else {
        $(".stepsUpLink").hide();
        $(".stepsLink").show();
        $(".steps").slideUp("fast", "linear");
    }
  });
```

Comment: yup, I added this. thanks all. The blind affect Memolition has would work too.